# What is the deal about https when using lxml?

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I am using lxml to parse html files given urls.

For example:

```
link = 'https://abc.com/def'
htmltree = lxml.html.parse(link)
```

My code is working well for most of the cases, the ones with `http://`. However, I found for every `https://` url, lxml simply gets an *IOError*. Does anyone know the reason? And possibly, how to correct this problem?

BTW, I want to stick to lxml than switch to BeautifulSoup given I've already got a quick finished programme.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know what's happening, but I get the same errors. HTTPS is probably not supported. You can easily work around this with `urllib2`, though:

```
from lxml import html
from urllib2 import urlopen

html.parse(urlopen('https://duckduckgo.com'))
```

Comment: `from urllib.request import urlopen` for python3

Answer (score 6):

From the `lxml` documentation:

> lxml can parse from a local file, an HTTP URL or an FTP URL

I don't see HTTPS in that sentence anywhere, so I assume it is not supported.

An easy workaround would be to retrieve the file using some other library that does support HTTPS, such as `urllib2`, and pass the retrieved document as a string to `lxml`.