# Python - use lxml to return value of title.text attrib

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I'm trying to figure out how to use lxml to parse the xml from a url to return the value of the title attribute. Does anyone know what I have wrong or what would return the Title value/text? So in the example below I want to return the value of 'Weeds - S05E05 - Van Nuys - HD TV'

XML from URL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.8.0">
<song id="11345" parent="11287" title="Weeds - S05E05 - Van Nuys - HD TV" album="Season 5" artist="Weeds" isDir="false" created="2009-07-06T22:21:16" duration="1638" bitRate="384" size="782304110" suffix="mkv" contentType="video/x-matroska" isVideo="true" path="Weeds/Season 5/Weeds - S05E05 - Van Nuys - HD TV.mkv" transcodedSuffix="flv" transcodedContentType="video/x-flv"/>
</subsonic-response>
```

My current Python code:

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'https://myurl.com'

tree = html.parse(urlopen(url))
songs = tree.findall('{*}song')
for song in songs:
    print song.attrib['title']
```

With the above code I get no data return, any ideas?

print out of tree =

```
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x0000000003348F48>
```

print out of songs =

```
[]
```

Comment: You are not using `lxml` functionality. Only the standard library `ElementTree` implementation is actually doing work in your example. The `import lxml.html as lh` can be safely removed from the code.

Comment: I've tried with the builtin ElementTree but could never get that to work either so I figured I'd try lxml. Just cannot figure out how to write the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are not actually using `lxml` in your code. You import the `lxml` HTML parser, but otherwise ignore it and just use the standard library [`xml.etree.ElementTree` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead.

Secondly, you search for `data/song` but you do not have any `data` elements in your document, so no matches will be found. And last, but not least, you have a document there that uses namespaces. You'll have to include those when searching for elements, or use a `{*}` wildcard search.

The following finds songs for you:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(URL)  # lxml can load URLs for you
songs = tree.findall('{*}song')
for song in songs:
    print song.attrib['title']
```

To use an explicit namespace, you'd have to replace the `{*}` wildcard with the full namespace URL; the default namespace is available in the `.nsmap` namespace dict on the `tree` object:

```
namespace = tree.nsmap[None]
songs = tree.findall('{%s}song' % namespace)
```

Comment: `import lxml
from lxml import etree

url = 'https://myurl.com'

tree = lxml.parse(url)  # lxml can load URLs for you
songs = tree.findall('{*}song')
for song in songs:
    print song.attrib['title']`

getting error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'

Comment: getting errors:`
tree = etree.parse(url)
  
  File "parser.pxi", line 1002, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:78623)
  File "parser.pxi", line 569, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:74567)
  File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:75458)
  File "parser.pxi", line 588, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:74760)
IOError: Error reading file 'https://myurl.com': failed to load external entity "https://myurl.com"`

Comment: Sorry edited that out to fit into the comment, however my url is https, does that matter?

Comment: @nutt318: Yes, `https` is not supported apparently, sorry about that. See [What is the deal about https when using lxml?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7882673)

Comment: I've updated my code in the above exmple, now I get nothing to return. Any ideas?

Comment: @nutt318: You are using the `html` parser. I suspect you should use the `etree` parser instead. You can use `print lxml.etree.tostring(tree)` to see what you retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue is with the fact that the `subsonic-response` tag has a `xmlns` attribute indicating that there is an xml namespace in effect. The below code takes that into account and correctly pigs up the song tags.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()
print root.findall('{http://subsonic.org/restapi}song')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, I used a combination of both of yours to get it working.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'https://myurl.com'
root = ET.parse(urlopen(url)).getroot()
for song in root:
    print song.attrib['title']
```

Comment: However when I put this into a variable it removes the spaces, any idea on how to keep the spaces?