# Error - OSError: Error reading file 'http://website' failed to load external entity "http://website/alpha.html"

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I am trying to do some visualisations with the volcano data. The data is downloaded and parsed using lxml. The Volcano World source page lists the volcano data in several HTML tables, which are each read into individual Pandas data frames that are appended to a list of data frames.

I keep getting this error :

OSError: Error reading file 'http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/oldroot/volcanoes/alpha.html': failed to load external entity "http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/oldroot/volcanoes/alpha.html

Can you assist with this code?

```
import json
from lxml import html
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


url ='http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/oldroot/volcanoes/alpha.html'
xpath = '//table'
tree = html.parse(url)
tables = tree.xpath(xpath)

table_dfs = []
for idx in range(4, len(tables)):
    df = pd.read_html(html.tostring(tables[idx]), header=0)[0]
    table_dfs.append(df)
```

## THIS IS THE ERROR I GET:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\envs\my_maps_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-10-d2be1cde3918>", line 3, in <module>
    tree = etree.fromstring(url)

  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3234, in lxml.etree.fromstring

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1757, in lxml.etree._parseDoc

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1068, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError

  File "<string>", line 1
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Comment: `tree = html.parse(url)` You can't call `html.parse()` on the plain URL; you have to visit the url and fetch its contents, and then call parse on that.

Comment: How do I visit and fetch contents with lxml?

Comment: My work around was to download the 'alpha.html' in url ='http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/oldroot/volcanoes/alpha.html' but I am trying to use the full HTTP link. Is that possible? and how?

Comment: First you mention an OSError, but the error below "THIS IS THE ERROR I GET:" is an XMLSyntaxError. I cannot reproduce any of them.

Comment: @JohnGordon: You *can* call `html.parse()` on a plain HTTP URL. It does not work with HTTPS though (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7882673/407651).